# Pass datas from ArrayList to ListView

Tags: c#, listview, arraylist, windows-forms-designer

Im new in C# programming, i have a Windows Form project, i trying to make a little CRUD using ArrayList and ListView, but.. the problem is to pass data from ArrayList to ListView i will show the problem!

In this class i initiliaze the Form and set some properties to ListView, and execute the read() method taht will read the data from ArrayList and pass to ListView!

```
namespace EmployeeCompany
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            

            //ListView Properties
            lstvPerson.View = View.Details;
            lstvPerson.FullRowSelect = true;

            //Construct Columns
            lstvPerson.Columns.Add("Name", 150);
            lstvPerson.Columns.Add("Position", 150);
            lstvPerson.Columns.Add("Team", 150);
            read();
        }

        //-------Problem
        private void read()
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = list.ToString();
            lstvPerson.Items.Add(item);            
        }

        private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.name = this.txtName.Text;
            person.position = this.txtPosition.Text;
            person.team = this.txtTeam.Text;
            list.Add(person);
        }

    }
}
```

In the output:

```
Name   |   Position  |   Team |
-------------------------------
System.Collection.ArrayList   |
                              |
                              |
                              |
                              |
```

Can someone kindly explain me why i get this error, and give some example about good pratics?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I recommend against using an ArrayList. For this problem, you should use a List instead. It is strongly typed and will make it easier for you to access each person's properties. Just change

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

to

```
var list = new List<Person>();
```

As for the ListView... if I recall correctly, the `Text` of `ListViewItem` is for the leftmost column. To access other columns, you need to use `SubItems`.

Also, you cannot assign the whole list to one item. You should assign one item from the list to one item in the ListView.

So instead of

> ```
> private void read()
> {
>     ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
>     item.Text = list.ToString();
>     lstvPerson.Items.Add(item);            
> }
> ```

Try

```
private void read()
{
    foreach(Person p in list)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Text = p.Name;
        item.SubItems.Add(p.Position);
        item.SubItems.Add(p.Team);
        lstvPerson.Items.Add(item);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Very thanks for your answer, but it still not working... the ListView stay null, but dont get error! i have a question... why i cant use `List<Person> list = new List<Person>` instead `var list = new List<Person>();` because when i used `var list = new List<Person>();` i get error - "var my only appear on script code"

Comment: The `var` keyword just means that you want the compiler to infer the type, so `var list = new List<Person>()` should do exactly the same thing as `List<Person> list = new List<Person>()`. But now that I'm looking at your code, I noticed `list` is a member variable, and `var` isn't allowed there.

Comment: Yes... and the ListView stay be Null, what can this be?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry... i mean, what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: the IDE dont show me any error, but the ListView stay empty and on debug the variable get the value!